# $('a').trigger('click'); not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I make jquery click `<a href="test.zip" id="mylink">test</a>`

```
<script>
    // this wont work
    $('#mylink').trigger('click'); 
</script>
```

Please can you help

Comment: what do you expect to happen here

Comment: the download must begin automatically - thanks

Comment: what do you expect will happen? The code you have is for firing of an event. It's not simulating the user clicking the link

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#mylink').trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 66):

If your intention is to navigate to the specified URL as if the user had clicked the link try calling the DOM `.click()` method instead of the jQuery `.click()` method:

```
$('#mylink')[0].click();
```

The jQuery `.click()` will call event handlers that you've bound but not cause the default click behaviour.

Answer (score 12):

You need to trigger the default `click` method, not the one by jQuery. This can be done by adding the default click option within a click event of jQuery using `this`.

```
<a href="http://about.com/"></a>
```

This is how the JavaScript looks. It basically creates the event when the DOM is ready, and clicks it intermediately, thus following the link.

```
$(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
        // 'this' is not a jQuery object, so it will use
        // the default click() function
        this.click();
    }).click();
});
```

To see a live example (opening about.com), see: http://jsfiddle.net/8H9UX/

Answer (score 4):

You need to wait until the DOM has finished loading. This can be done with jQuery. The anonymous function is run at page load once all the elements are available in the DOM.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#mylink').trigger('click');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Yes - at page load an event is emitted informing that the DOM is now available. jQuery listens to this event and fires any bound listeners as per my example.

Answer (score 3):

Just click:

```
$("#mylink").click();
```

If your scripts are in the head then you need to ensure that the element exists, so the script should be executed when document is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#mylink").click();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
setTimeout(() => {
$("#mylink")[0].click();
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are expecting the file to get downloaded, it will not happen becauer [trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) will not trigger the default event.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('mylink').click();
```

---

`trigger('click')` will fire the click event but not the default one.

```
$('a').click(function(){ alert('triggered') }) // this will be fired by trigger
```

Answer (score 1):

use the following way.... since you want to download the file prevent the link from navigating.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mylink').click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();  //stop the browser navigating
       window.location.href = 'test.zip';
    });
});
```

Comment: OP is trying to progammatically force a click, not respond to a click from the user.

Answer (score -1):

your above code will not work because you have assigned value in `href` and then you want some operation `onclick` of this anchor tag.

```
<a href="test.zip" id="mylink">test</a>
```

first of all you have assigned `.zip` to href. So it will open zip file onclick first and will not trigger any other operation in `onclick` trigger.

so whatever operation you want to do , perform it first then open `.zip`

use code like below

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="mylink">test</a>

$('#mylink').click(function(){
    // do your operation here
    // now open zip 
});
```