# jQuery - trigger("click") & .click working in console but not working in script

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is what i try in console:

```
$("#element a:eq(0)").click();
```

And it is working perfectly.
Here is what i try in script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log($("#element a:eq(0)"));
    $("#element a:eq(0)").click();
    $("#element a:eq(0)").trigger("click");
});
```

Then when i refresh the page i can see in the console log that the element is perfectly selected, however there is no click triggered. Do you see any possible reason of why this is not working ?

Comment: Can you share HTML a bit

Comment: what should the element do? maybe its dependend on another script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$('a').trigger('click'); not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17105015/a-triggerclick-not-working)

Comment: everything is working fine. i've made the link to hide inside the click function, and on load, it's triggering the click and thus hiding the link. see here https://jsfiddle.net/82rhLvu1/1/   you need to give us more details about the rest of the code

Comment: **Exactly** what do you see in the console log?  A missing element would still be shown as [Object] as you'd get an empty jquery object.  Change it to `console.log($("#element a:eq(0)").length);` to be sure.

Comment: Length is 1 that means element is found.

Comment: Your code working fine what is not working in fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Your event is perfectly triggerd , it shows nothing because there is no event listener defined on the click event , So if you define the click event you'll see that the event will trigger twise (`.click()` and `.trigger('click')`) ,

Also if you want to trigger the redirect to href just add location.href = this.href and the click + redirection will fire .

Please see below snippet :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log($("#element a:eq(0)"));
     
    $("#element a:eq(0)").click(function() {
      alert("#element a:eq(0) clicked");
      //if you want to redirect to href page just incomment the below line 
      //location.href = this.href;
    });
    
    $("#element a:eq(0)").click();
    
    $("#element a:eq(0)").trigger("click");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="element" >
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44364289/jquery-triggerclick-click-working-in-console-but-not-working-in-script" >1</a>
  <a href="#2" >2</a>
  <a href="#3" >3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this help  you :)