# Cannot open link in jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

Code:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <a id="go" href="go">go</a>

  <script>
    $("#go").trigger("click");
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

This script doesn't open the link `go` when visiting the page.

Comment: I've turned your code into an executable snippet and it works. Are you sure you have the body script *after* the element?

Comment: Solution there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17105252/5163311

Comment: That doesn't seem to be needed when I run your code above.

Comment: I've tested the code above externally of my app. It doesn't work, and I don't know why.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: No there is no error in the console

Comment: If you put `console.log($("#go").length);` before `$("#go").trigger("click");`, what does it show?

Answer (score 1):

`.trigger("click")` will trigger the bound event, but not the direct click.
In your case it will work:

```js
go.click();
```

```html
<a id="go" href="https://go" target="_blank">go</a>
```